# Verify if a word have a letter repeated in any position

Tags: regex

I'd like know if there are a way to test if a word have a letter repeated in any position?

I'm currently using this regex to test it, but not work, becouse if I add more then 2 's' the test returns true.

```
  /s{0,2}/.test('süuaãpérbrôséê'); //expected true
  /s{0,2}/.test('ssüuaãpérbrôéê'); //expected true
  /s{0,2}/.test('süuaãpérbrôéê'); //expected true
  /s{0,2}/.test('süuaãpérbrôséês'); //expected fail
```

Thanks.

Comment: What language/regex flavor is this in?

Comment: I'm testing in js, but it will be used on php.

Comment: Can you provide example Strings of what you are parsing and what you are expecting pass your test and what you are expecting to fail. Currently it is very unclear what is expected

Comment: sure, I put the examples on post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I found to resolve this problem is using php preg_match_all, on this way I can count how much times the character repeat.

```
  $s = 'süuaãpérbrôséê';
  preg_match_all('/s/i', $s, $m);
  echo count($m[0]); //outputs 2
```

My initial idea was pass a regex and use preg_match to verify the match exists in a determined number of times, but I think that it's not possible, so I'll create a method that receive the word and the regex that I need match and it will return the number of matches.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
/s{2,}/
```

or generally for any character:

```
/(.)\1/
```

Comment: your examples works only if I have at least 2 's' on my word, but at my case, some times I'll not have any or just one or two. If I have more then 2 so the word will be considered wrong and will be discarded.

Comment: ok, but on this way how can I test with the letter exists and is repeated (or not) up to twice?

Answer (score 0):

`/(\w)\1/` finds two alphanumeric characters next to each other

This will find and replace the duplicates:
`s/(\w)\1/$1/`

Comment: I'd like test the repetitions not just on two characters next to each other, I need test if characters exists even if they are separated by other (see my string exemple above).

Answer (score 0):

using lookahead you can achieve something like that:

```
^(?=.*(\w)(.*\1){1}.*$)((?!\1).)*\1(((?!\1).)*\1){1}((?!\1).)*$
```

Where `{1}` is number of repeatings minus 1, so for finding if there are three repeations this would look like:

```
^(?=.*(\w)(.*\1){2}.*$)((?!\1).)*\1(((?!\1).)*\1){2}((?!\1).)*$
```

And for two or three:

```
^(?=.*(\w)(.*\1){1,2}.*$)((?!\1).)*\1(((?!\1).)*\1){1,2}((?!\1).)*$
```

etc.

The lookaheads with backreferences can be very powerful :)